# Is this a valid proof of this math challenge problem?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, contest-math

From a fixed point P not in a given plane, three mutually perpendicular line segments are drawn terminating in the plane. Let a, b, c denote the lengths of the three segments. Show that $$\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}$$ has a constant value for all allowable configurations.

Here's my proof: 
Vector (a,b,c) can be used to represent the plane. Note that vectors with different magnitudes but equivalent directions represent parallel planes such that plane (xk,yk,zk) is parallel to (x,y,z). Let there be a vector (h,i,j) s.t it is equal to vector (x,y,z). No operations can be performed on (x,y,z) s.t x=/=h, y=/=i, z=/=j. Q.E.D.

This is my first attempt at doing very clever proofs, so please let me know if this is not a sufficient proof.

My proof is a one by contradiction. Basically it's saying that there is nothing you can do to vector (x,y,z) to make it different and still equivalent to another vector. The sentence before that on magnitudes is to emphasize that even though vectors have the same direction, without the same magnitudes they simply represent planes that are parallel to each other.

Comment: I don't think your proof's statements have anything to do with the problem.

Comment: Let P=(0,0,0)  and let the 3 lines from P be the co-ordinate axes. The plane is the set of (x,y,z) for which x/a + y/b +z/c =1. Prove that the shortest distance from P to the plane is $ 1/a^2 +1/b^2 +c^2$.  Taking 3 different mutually orthogonal lines from P represents a change to a different set of axes still centered on P, but the distance from P to the plane is constant,

Comment: Oh? I interpretted the problem as "If you adjust the values of a,b, and c, you get a certain plane that intersects their endpoints opposite P. Show that there is only one way to get each configuration of the plane (each way the plane can be oriented) to show that the sum of 1/a^2 + 1/b^2 + 1/c^2 must be constant if a,b, and c can only have one value for each configuration."

Comment: I see where my interpretation of the problem was wrong. When it said " constant value for all allowable configurations", I assumed it meant that you need to show there are no two ways to get the same plane (if there were, there would be more a,b, and c values that get it). Now I see it really means that the distance remains constant regardless of whether you change it's orientation. Sorry about that. Does my proof at least work for my interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, the problem has been misread.

Here's an (inelegant) solution the problem. This is one of those sad coordinate-geometry arguments that illuminates very little about the geometry going on here, but can be done with bullet-headed algebraic computation.

If the statement of the problem is true, the constant value must be:
$$\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}=\frac{1}{d^2}\tag{1}$$

where $d$ is the distance of the point $P$ to the plane. This is because you can rotate your frame of vectors $\mathbf a,\mathbf b,\mathbf c$ so that only $\mathbf a$ is on the plane and $\mathbf b,\mathbf c$ are essentially infinite. So the constant value, if it exists, has to be $\frac{1}{d^2}$, where $d$ is the distance from $P$ to the plane.

(While the problem specifically states that $\mathbf b,\mathbf c$ must be on the plane, what this really amounts to is rotating the frame so that $\mathbf a$ is close to the nearest point to $p$, and $\mathbf b,\mathbf c$ are very far away.)

So another way to state this theorem is to say that if you have a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ which is distant $d$ from the origin and contains $(a,0,0),(0,b,0),$ and $(0,0,c)$, then $$\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}=\frac{1}{d^2}.$$

Let $\mathbf v=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ be the point on the plane closes to $(0,0,0)$. Then the plane can be written as the set of $(x,y,z)$.

$$\mathbf v\cdot(x,y,z)=\mathbf v\cdot \mathbf v=d^2$$

In particular, then $$\mathbf v\cdot(a,0,0)=ax_0=d^2\\
\mathbf v\cdot(0,b,0)=by_0=d^2\\
\mathbf v\cdot(0,0,c)=cz_0=d^2$$
  So:

$$\frac{1}{a^2} = \frac{x_0^2}{d^4}\\
\frac{1}{b^2} = \frac{y_0^2}{d^4}\\
\frac{1}{c^2} = \frac{z_0^2}{d^4}$$

So:
$$\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}=\frac{x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2}{d^4}=\frac{1}{d^2}.$$

Alternative approach: Given $a,b,c\neq 0$, the plane through $(a,0,0),(0,b,0),(0,0,c)$ in $\mathbb R^3$ has equation:

$$\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=1$$

Find the nearest point to the origin using this equation, and show $(1)$.

A useful theorem:

> The nearest point to the origin on the plane $$\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z=C$$
>   is a scalar multiple of $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$, specifically:
>   $$(x,y,z)=\frac{C}{\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$$

Then we see that $d^2=x^2+y^2+z^2=\frac{C^2}{\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2}$.